# How to initialize fields in F# before the constructor gets called?

Tags: c#, .net, function, f#, delegates

This code doesn't work properly, because `GetEntriesChangedObservable` is called from the base constructor and `FMyEntries` is `null` because it's own constructor wasn't called yet.

```
type MyEnumDefinition () = 
    inherit DynamicEnumDefinitionBase<MyEnumDefinition> ()

    let FMyEntries : ObservableCollection<string> = ObservableCollection<string>()

    //gets called from base constructor
    override this.GetEntriesChangedObservable() =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>( 
            (fun h -> FMyEntries.CollectionChanged.AddHandler h), //FMyEntries is null
            (fun h -> FMyEntries.CollectionChanged.RemoveHandler h)) //FMyEntries is null
```

How should `FMyEntries` be initialized so that it has a value before any constructor gets called?

In C# it would look like this:

```
    //initialized before constructor
    ObservableCollection<string> FMyEntries = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    //gets called from base constructor
    protected override IObservable<object> GetEntriesChangedObservable()
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
            h => FMyEntries.CollectionChanged += h,
            h => FMyEntries.CollectionChanged -= h);
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
Short answer, it is not possible! Even when applying the hack suggested by Fyodor Soikin the F# runtime checks the initialization process and throws an exception if the constructor tries to access any member if its own instance.

I solved it in the end by adding an Initialize() function that did the same as the constructor.

Comment: What's the call stack at the point where you find `FMyEntries` to be null?

Comment: Good point, was on the wrong track. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's not possible in F# to initialize fields/properties before calling the base constructor, so you won't be able to create such class (here I have to note: it is generally not good design for the ancestor constructor to count on the descendant being initialized; I know, small consolation).

But there is one exception: in an object expression, closed variables get initialized before the base constructor is called. So you can apply this slightly ugly workaround:

```
type [<AbstractClass>] MyEnumDefinition() = 
    inherit DynamicEnumDefinitionBase<MyEnumDefinition> ()

    abstract member GetMyEntries: unit -> ObservableCollection<string>

    override this.GetEntriesChangedObservable() =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>( 
            (fun h -> this.GetMyEntries().CollectionChanged.AddHandler h), 
            (fun h -> this.GetMyEntries().CollectionChanged.RemoveHandler h)))

let mkMyEnumDefinition() =
   let MyEntries = ObservableCollection<string>()
   { new MyEnumDefinition() with override __.GetMyEntries() = MyEntries }
```

**NOTE**:
Normally you could create the base class directly (i.e. `{ new DynamicEnumDefinitionBase with ... }`), but in this case you *have* to have a derived class to supply as generic parameter. Another design smell.

Comment: This looks genius, but unfortunately doesn't work in my case because the base class will be a singleton and constructs the singleton instance with the primary constructor of the subclass, that's why it needs the subclass as generic parameter and has the new() constraint on it. Can you think of a solution with a GetMyEntries function that checks the FMyEntries on access and if it is null then initializes it?

Comment: my current approach is here: https://pastebin.com/yTXw1CXX only problem is, that the two do statements do not work like this anymore...

Comment: Nah, didn't work as F# checks member access from the constructor and throws a "The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized." exception... So I'll try further with abstract class and primary constructor

Comment: I seems like nothing helps, this exception is not going away. I ended up with introducing an Initialize() method that gets called on first access to the singleton.